# detecting combo box selected item in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm using VS2010,C# to develop my ASP.NET web app, I've implemented an internal communication page which acts like email systems, of course recipients can be selected from a combo box which lists user names of the system.
Is there any way that I can use client side (JavaScript) to detect selected item of my combo box, so that I can disable combo box autopostback (post backing to the server takes a lot of time and can annoy the user). I want to write name of the selected user (i.e. combo box selected item) in a table (so that user can see the recipient list). There can be any number of selection from the combo box (of course there is always one item selectable at a time).

also user should be able to remove each recipient by click on its name, meanwhile I want to have list of selected users in server side, I should use hidden tag?

I've seen above scenario in another site working with ASP.NET and it was really smooth, so I'm going to implement it.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

all you need to use is `JQuery` and read some articles, for example check this one:

http://elegantcode.com/2009/07/01/jquery-playing-with-select-dropdownlistcombobox/

examples:

get currently selected value:

```
$("#ComboBox").val()
```

execute some code when selected item changes:

```
$("#ComboBox").change(function() { /* do something here */ });
```

programmatically set selected item:

```
$("#ComboBox").val(2);
```